# Is it exit way to close all tabs with CURRENT site in Safari?

Tags: macos, browser, terminal, safari, applescript

As an active browser user, I want to be able to close all tabs related only to a particular site after I have finished the project or finised with current site.

I know there are shortcuts that can quickly close all tabs
- tabs other than current
- web browser
- current window 
- etc

But there is no way to close only the desired site.

Is it possible to quickly close only the current site Using
browser or
the terminal with AppleScript or BetterTouchTool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script closes every tab in every window of Safari that has the same domain as the current tab:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set theURL to URL of current tab
    end tell
    set theDomain to my domainOfURL(theURL)
    set windowList to every window
    repeat with aWindow in windowList
        tell aWindow
            close (every tab whose URL begins with theDomain)
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

on domainOfURL(aURL)
    set tid to my text item delimiters
    set my text item delimiters to "/"
    set theDomain to text items 1 through 3 of aURL as text
    set my text item delimiters to tid
    return theDomain
end domainOfURL
```